# Prove this inequality $P=\sum _{cyc}\frac{1}{xy+1}\ge \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

For $x,y,z>0$ and $xyz=1$. Prove that $$P=\frac{1}{xy+1}+\frac{1}{yz+1}+\frac{1}{xz+1}\ge \frac{3}{2}$$

---

We have : $\frac{1}{xy+1}=\frac{z}{xyz+z}=\frac{z}{z+1}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{z}{z+1}\ge \frac{3}{2}$

**Idea 1:** $\sum _{cyc}\frac{x}{x+1}=\sum _{cyc}\left(1-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)=3-\left(\sum _{cyc}\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$

I can't continue

**Idea 2:** Use Am-gm: $\frac{x}{x+1}+\frac{y}{y+1}+\frac{z}{z+1}\ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{xyz}{\left(x+1\right)\left(y+1\right)\left(z+1\right)}}\ge \frac{3}{2}$

$\Rightarrow \left(x+1\right)\left(y+1\right)\left(z+1\right)\le 8\forall xyz=1;x,y,z>0$ ?? It's wrong. Help

Comment: What inequality?

Comment: $\ge \frac{3}{2}$ sorry

Answer (score 0):

Take $x = y = \frac{1}{2} \wedge z = 4$ and you will quickly see that the conjecture is false.

Answer (score 0):

This inequality is wrong! Try $z\rightarrow0^+$.

For example, $y=z=0.1$ and $x=100$.